# React warning when selecting an option from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have the following Select statement into a React component

```
<Select
   id="type"
   className={classes.formComponent}
   onChange={ e => handleDropDownListEvent(e) }
   required
   defaultValue="DEFAULT"
   >
   <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
   <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
   <option value="Opt3">
      Opt3
   </option>
   <option defaultValue="DEFAULT" disabled>
      Choose an event
   </option>
</Select>
```

And when I'm trying to select an option in UI from this drop down list I'm getting the following warning in chrome console:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
    in option (at HealthKitForm.tsx:134)
    in ul (created by ForwardRef(List))
    in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (created by ForwardRef(MenuList))
    in ForwardRef(MenuList) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Grow))
    in ForwardRef(Grow) (created by TrapFocus)
    in TrapFocus (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Portal) (created by ForwardRef(Modal))
    in ForwardRef(Modal) (created by ForwardRef(Popover))
    in ForwardRef(Popover) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Popover)) (created by ForwardRef(Menu))
    in ForwardRef(Menu) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Menu)) (created by ForwardRef(SelectInput))
    in ForwardRef(SelectInput) (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(InputBase))
    in ForwardRef(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by ForwardRef(Input))
    in ForwardRef(Input) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Input)) (created by ForwardRef(Select))
    in ForwardRef(Select) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)) (at HealthKitForm.tsx:128)
    in form (at HealthKitForm.tsx:127)
    in div (at HealthKitForm.tsx:125)
    in HealthKitForm (at src/index.tsx:11)
    in SmilerProvider (at src/index.tsx:10)
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this warning? Also what kind of event is generated when I'm selecting an option because I need the type of the event on signature of **handleDropDownListEvent(event: type???)**

Comment: Check the type within the `Select` library, we can't guess where it comes from as it is a custom component.

Comment: Just curious, is this `Select` from Material UI?

Comment: @foyss yes it is

Comment: I'd recommend setting defaultValue as empty, and having a look at `FormControl`, `InputLabel`, and `MenuItem` from the Material UI Library

Comment: Added my suggestion below :) have a nice day

Comment: Thanx for suggestion, have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning for `defaultValue` in `option`, you should change it to `value="DEFAULT"`:

```
<Select defaultValue="DEFAULT">
  ...
  // not defaultValue ="DEFAULT"
  <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>
    Choose an event
  </option>
</Select>
```

Update by checking the documentation you need to use `MenuItem` not option tag

```
<Select labelId="label" id="select" value="20">
  <MenuItem value="10">Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="20">Twenty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: I changed like you said and I get the same warning.

Comment: make a sandbox [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

I see that your question is answered, but may I recommend an improvement from the code you have provided so far...

With the use of `FormControl`, `InputLabel`, and `MenuItem` from the Material UI library, managing Selects become tremendously easier as well as [styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/)

```
const optionsArray = [Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4]

<FormControl> 
   <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-select" variant='outlined'> 
      SELECT NAME 
   </InputLabel>
   <Select 
      defaultValue="" 
      className={classes.formComponent} 
      onChange={e => handleDropDownListEvent(e)}>
      {optionsArray.map((option, index) =>
         <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
      )}                            
   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, but this can all be added in a functional component and be reused throughout your application :)

Comment: and in handleDropDownListEvent do you know which type event can be? I can't find anything.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, but you can try doing it like this; `onChange={handleDropDownListEvent('SelectName')}` with the ES6 function looking like `const handleDropDownListEvent = name => event => { console.log(event) };` and checking the console

Answer (score 0):

As a error already stated that

```
Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>
```

Which mean you can not use defaultValue on option tag you can only use on select tag. But this is how you can set default value on the option using `selected` attribute

```
<select name = "dropdown">
  <option value = "Java">Java</option>
  <option value = "Discrete Mathematics" selected>Discrete Mathematics</option>
  <option value = "Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did the changes and I get same warning.

Comment: Can you share with me the library you are using ? I can take a look on the documentation

Comment: Sure, library: import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'.